# Параметр ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS в Jetty

Tags: java, servlet, jetty, context, handlers

Здравствуйте.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, на что влияет параметр `options` конструктора  `ServletContextHandler(int options)`. Вот полное имя класса:     `org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler;`
В самом классе определены 4 константы, которые, видимо, могут выступать в качестве параметра конструктора:

```
public final static int SESSIONS=1;
public final static int SECURITY=2;
public final static int NO_SESSIONS=0;
public final static int NO_SECURITY=0;
```

Также, конструктор может быть вообще без параметров`ServletContextHandler()`.
Во многих примерах кода встречается строчка:

```
ServletContextHandler context = new ServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);
```

В чём отличие этого конструктора от конструктора без параметра:

```
ServletContextHandler context = new ServletContextHandler();
```

или с параметром `SECURITY`

```
ServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.SECURITY);
```

Answer (score 2):

Перечисление *ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS, NO_SECURITY ...* необходимо для установки `SessionHandler` и `SecurityHandler` и т.д.
Например, если использовать значение `NO_SESSIONS` или `NO_SECURITY`, то соответствующие обработчики(handlers) не будут созданы при вызове конструктора `ServletContextHandler`.

Даже если вы вызываете ServletContexHandler без параметра, то вы можете вручную добавить `SecurityHandler` и `SessionHandler`, главное, до запуска сервера.

Для чего мы указываем это вместо того, чтобы вызвать контруктор без параметров? Думаю, для явного указания типа контекстного хендлера.